# Payment history No records returned

Tags: c#, paypal, .net-4.5, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to get a list of transactions from my business paypal account through the rest API.

It authenticates but returns no records both in sandbox and live ( there are plenty in live ) .

Even using the .NET sample code and entering my credentials - it doesn't work!

Comment: Please show some of your code.

Comment: It's not my code - it's straight out of the .NET sample app!  All I did was change credentials.  I also tried using it in my own app.

    var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
    var paymentList = Payment.List(apiContext, count: 10, startIndex: 5

Comment: Please note also - we are in New Zealand.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the REST API payment history will only return REST API transactions.  If you want to pull general transaction history from PayPal you'll need to use the Classic API, specifically TransactionSearch, which would return a list of transactions, and then GetTransactionDetails could be used to pull individual transaction details.

Comment: Ok . Be nice if we could use rest end to end.. Transaction search it pretty fiddly in classic api